# How to uninstall mysql on redhat linux version 5

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, rpm

I have identified the rpm to uninstall which is the following:

mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6

I run the following rpm command to uninstall it:

```
rpm -e mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
```

Then I receive a dependency error, basically saying that it cant remove this rpm because it has a dependancy on the rpm exim-4.63-10.el5.x86_64. see error below:

```
libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by (installed) exim-4.63-10.el5.x86_64
libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by (installed) exim-4.63-10.el5.x86_64
```

I then looked up what exim-4.63-10.el5.x86_64 actually is and determined that its a email application similar to sendmail.  So I attempted to uninstall it and received some other dependency errors.

Is there a way to have the rpm command ignore the dependency or am i approaching this the wrong way.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reason not to use Yum?

`yum erase mysql` will resolve the dependencies and show you every thing it would need to remove.

Comment: Well that did work quite cleanly!

Answer (score 4):

You can tell RPM to ignore dependencies and just rip stuff out with the --nodeps flag.  I've had to do it in some cases, but make sure you reeeally understand what's depending on those packages.

Another neat trick is to run `rpm -qa|grep <thing you want to uninstall>|xargs rpm -e`, that will remove all of the packages with "thing you want to uninstall" in the name.  I;ve found a lot of times this helps alleviate dependencies if they're all related to the same install.

Comment: Nice command!  I appreciate it.. It looks like its all pointing back to sendmail.. this is strictly going to be a db server but just wanted to start with a fresh install.

Comment: No prob, just an fyi, if you still need it, --nodeps, or sometimes also, the --allmatches flag, they go at the end of that last command after -e - jus tin case people who find this don't already know.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
yum remove mysql mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to remove an rpm without checking dependencies you can always use the --nodeps flag like so:

`rpm -e mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 --nodeps`